# phpMyAdmin allow iframe access

Tags: phpmyadmin

How can I allow accessing my phpMyAdmin using iframe ? I have try removing `cross_framing_protection.js`, no change.

Using this simple iframe code

```
<iframe src="http://somedomain.com/phpMyAdmin/"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just add to config.inc.php file this line:

```
$cfg['AllowThirdPartyFraming'] = true;
```

Comment: I was looking for this for the last hour, thanks for sharing.